# How can I pad a value with leading zeros when value equals to one digit number?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I want to convert seconds into minutes.
For example 61 seconds should be displayed like 1:01 (not 1:1)
I tried with `parseInt(sec / 60)` : `sec % 60`.
If `sec=61` it is showing like `1:1`.

I have data from music API that gives me music duration in seconds and I have to convert them into minutes.
I tried

```
{parseInt(data.duration / 60 )} : {data.duration % 60}
```

sometimes it is giving me `3:35, 3:24` and `3:1`. I have to add 0 before 1  as well. How can I do it
I also tried with

```
{parseInt(data.duration / 60 )} : {parseFloat(data.duration % 60).toFixed(2)}
```

it is showing `1:1.00`
I want to display it like `1:01`.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: FYI, works fine for me... `\`${parseInt(sec / 60)}:${sec % 60}\`` though personally, I'd use `Math.floor()` instead of `parseInt()`

Comment: it means 1 minute and 10 seconds. But it is showing like 1 minutes and 1 seconds. It is automatically removing 0 from end

Comment: Running `parseInt(70 / 60) + ":" + 70 % 60` in the console gives me `'1:10'`

Comment: Actually, I have data from music API. It gives me music duration with seconds. But I have to convert it into minutes. I tried with the code that I wrote above

Comment: No repro ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/young-monad-ocin8?file=/src/App.tsx. 70s shows as `1 : 10`. I suspect the value is actually `61` and not `70`

Comment: Oh. Yes you are right

Comment: So is your real question how to display `61` as `1:01`?

Comment: Yes. I edited question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I pad a value with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1267283/283366)

Comment: Not exactly, Because it will add 0 to all my results like: 1:072 it should add 0 when float num equals to 1 digit number

Answer (score 2):

try this

```js
const convertToTime = (time) => (time < 10 ? `0${time}` : time);

const sec = 69;
const result = `${convertToTime(parseInt(sec / 60))}:${convertToTime(sec % 60)}`;;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice, but why re-assign `time` in the function body?

Comment: @Phil that can be reused for the day, hour, min, sec, etc. don't want to write the same condition multiple times `(time < 10 ? (time = `0${time}`): time)`.

Comment: Sorry, not following you there.

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry for my bad, It was a typo I converted the function to the arrow function I left that. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: FYI, `parseInt()` should specify the radix. Personally, I would use `Math.floor()` instead

Comment: @Muhsin what is not working?

Comment: Hi Sorry. Bro my bad I forgot to add parseInt() thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
function parseTime(time) {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    const second = time % 60;
    // return `${minutes}:${second < 10 ? "0" : ""}${second}`;
    return `${minutes}:${second.toString().padStart(2, "0")}`;
}
```

You can use the if else statement to verify the second or use padStart to make sure the length of the second is always 2.

Comment: hi thanks it it working

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your support. I found the answer.
Thank to @ace1234

```
{parseInt(data.duration / 60)} : {parseFloat(data.duration % 60 ).toString().padStart(2, "0")
```

Comment: Congrats. When i finished answering your question, i realized that you had solved it while i was writing the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can write a logic to handle it or use [padStart](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

```js
const something = 7;

const fun1 = (s) => s < 10 ? `0${s}` : s;
const fun2 = (s) => s.toString().padStart(2, '0');

console.log( fun1(something) );
console.log( fun2(something) );
```

Answer (score -2):

Do it like

```
let min = sec/60;
```

And display like

`min`: `sec - (min*60)`